# Faculty funding in biomedical postgraduate-only institutions

Tags: funding, job-search, biology, biotechnology

What is the model for faculty funding in biomedical postgraduate-only or research-only institutions?

I understand the distinction between "soft" vs "hard" money and I was told that in medical schools non-clinical tenure-track faculty is usually a soft-money position. I can't find any information regarding the funding model for places like Rockefeller University or Sloan Kettering Center.

It seems that in Rockefeller they pay salary for tenured faculty, but not for tenure track (news article from 2008). What about research institutes like Scripps or Cold Spring Harbor Lab? Does anybody have more concrete information?

Thank you in advance for any info!

Comment: Since you are focused on a small set of institutions, why not just ask them? The information is probably available.

Comment: Good point. I am not sure that they will be willing to share this information through the general inquiry email account, but it does not hurt to ask.

Comment: You might need to contact someone involved with employment contracts. The name of the office will vary, but you can normally find contact information for most offices on university web sites.